# Customize Foundation label color with Sass

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, web-essentials

I'm trying to change the color of Foundation labels.  I think I'm doing this correctly according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115734/47589).

My site.scss:

```
@import "normalize";

$row-width: '1080px';
$label-font-color: #333333;

@import "foundation";
@import "foundation.mvc";

.test {
    color: $label-font-color;
}
```

I've confirmed that changes to site.scss are getting compiled.  The `$row-width` setting is getting used as expected.  What am I doing wrong?  Why is the label color still the default `$4d4d4d`?

```
/* Label Styles */
label {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4d4d4d;         /* <-------- argh! */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  /* Styles for required inputs */
}

.test {
  color: #333333;  /* <--- why is this one correct? */
}
```

If I edit Foundation's _labels.scss, appending this:

```
.test {
    color: $label-font-color;
}
```

to the end of the file, it shows up in the generated css *correctly*.  Why is the label ignoring it, though?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Turns out the `label` CSS is generated from Foundation's _forms.scss, *not* _labels.scss.  The generated CSS contains a `label` CSS rule and a `.label` CSS rule, and I hadn't noticed the difference.

Changing my variable to `$form-label-font-color` did the trick.

```
$form-label-font-color: #333333;
```